# How to send a single log entry with a text message and a JSON payload using @google-cloud/logging?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-logging

Following this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries#windows) and some other docs, I have this code, which is working fine, as far as sending logs to my project's Cloud Logging:

**testLogging.ts**

```
import { Logging } from "@google-cloud/logging";

const PROJECT_ID = "MY_PROJECT_ID";
const REGION = "MY_REGION";
const SERVICE_NAME = "MY_SERVICE_NAME";

const logging = new Logging({ projectId: PROJECT_ID });
const logName = "my-logs"; 
const log = logging.log(logName);

const resource = {
  type: "cloud_run_revision",     // I'M LOGGING FOR A CLOUD RUN CONTAINER
  labels: {
    service_name: SERVICE_NAME,
    location: REGION,
    project_id: PROJECT_ID,
    revision_name: "",
    configuration_name: ""
  }
};

const text_msg = `MY ERROR MSG`;
const json_payload = { foo: "bar" };

const text_entry = log.entry(
  { resource,  severity: "ERROR" },
  text_msg
);

const json_entry = log.entry(
  { resource,  severity: "ERROR" },
  json_payload 
);

log.write(text_entry);
log.write(json_entry);
```

They are working. And this is getting logged:

[image]

But so far I've only been able to log it separately. And I'd like to send a single log entry with a text message and a JSON payload. How can I do that?

**References:**

- https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries#windows
- https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-logging/blob/master/samples/logs.js
- https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/api/v2/resource-list#resource-types
- https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/MonitoredResource
- https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/logging/latest/

Comment: No, I was wrong about protobuf because the library does the object to protobuf conversion internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of @BrianBurton and his answer, I've found a way to do it:

From the [LogEntry reference doc](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry), wee see that the payload must be **one of the following:** `protoPayload`, `textPayload` or `jsonPayload`.

[image]

But I just found out that if you add a `message` field to your `jsonPayload` object, it will be displayed as the error or log message.

For example:

```
const json_payload = { message: "SOMETHING HAPPENED", foo: "bar" };

const json_entry = log.entry(
  { resource,  
    severity: "ERROR",
  },
  json_payload
);

log.write(json_entry);
```

Results in:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Update after testing**

This version is what I tested with and works, so see if you can adapt it to your needs.

```
const {Logging} = require("@google-cloud/logging");

const PROJECT_ID = "PROJECT_ID";
const REGION = "REGION";
const SERVICE_NAME = "MY_SERVICE_NAME";
const KEYFILE_PATH = "keyfile.json";

const logging = new Logging({ projectId: PROJECT_ID, keyFile: KEYFILE_PATH, fallback: false });
const logName = "my-log";
const log = logging.log(logName);

const resource = {
    type: "cloud_run_revision",     // I'M LOGGING FOR A CLOUD RUN CONTAINER
    labels: {
        service_name: SERVICE_NAME,
        location: REGION,
        project_id: PROJECT_ID,
        revision_name: "",
        configuration_name: ""
    }
};

const text_msg = `MY ERROR MSG`;
const json_payload = { foo: "bar" };

// The metadata associated with the entry
const metadata = {
    resource,
    severity: 'ERROR',
    textPayload: text_msg,
    jsonPayload: json_payload
};

// Prepares a log entry
const entry = log.entry(metadata);

async function writeLog() {
    await log.write(entry);
    console.log('Logged!');
}

writeLog();
```

This results in:
[image: Logging Results]

---

**Original Post**

The `entry()` function accepts [multiple configurations](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-logging/blob/543533a02f293028081e7d31e3a98be1677b426a/src/log.ts#L368), try dropping the second parameter and just passing it all in the [metadata.](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-logging/blob/543533a02f293028081e7d31e3a98be1677b426a/protos/protos.d.ts#L27)

```
  log.entry({
    resource,
    severity: "ERROR",
    jsonPayload: json_payload,
    textPayload: text_payload
  });
```

Comment: Thanks. Please, see the type error I'm getting when trying to pass an object to the `jsonPayload` property. **UPDATE:** Never mind, once I've removed the second argument of the `log.entry()` call, the type error is now gone.

Comment: Good deal, going straight to the code is usually way more insightful than the docs.

Comment: But there is a problem. The log is not being shown anymore. I'm building the entry exactly like your answer and then doing `log.write(the_entry)`. It doesn't trigger any errors but the log is not really being sent because it's not showing on my reports. Maybe I'll need to send the text `msg` as the second argument. And build the struct like you suggested on your edit. Could you add it back?

Comment: I've updated my question with a new attempt using your suggestion of the `pb-util` package. I'm almost there, but not quiet yet.

Comment: I'll test it out

Comment: Thanks. See the last screen I've added to question. I think you can't set `jsonPayload` and `textPayload` at the same time. Maybe what I'd like to do is impossible?

Comment: No it's possible, just tested it out.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Finally found a way to do it. Using just `jsonPayload`. I've added an answer. Thank you so much for your help.